# How to make resberry-pi to webserver

Tags: database, webserver, cloud

**What is the simple easy way to make resberry-pi to webserver and attach it to cloud.I search a lot but no one has easy way to make webserver**. 
**I want to send text data to resberry-pi and then use text to make arduno work.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"...make raspberry-pi webserver..." is a very broad term. It all depends on what kind task you want that server to accomplish and what kind of server you want to set up for that. First and foremost you would need a linux(or other) OS installed in your Pi. Then based on what you want to do, you can set up a web server in your pi like Apache, nginx, node etc. And taking data and attaching it to the could can also have a variety of purpose, are you planning to make a proxy to an Amazon web service? or something else. Here are a few links that might help you, but if you want furhter help please, be more specific

Using pi as a proxy cache
https://the-server.ninja/2016/03/26/using-a-raspberry-pi-as-a-squid-proxy-cache/

Node server on Pi
https://nodered.org/docs/hardware/raspberrypi

Pi and AWS
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-sdk-setup.html

Comment: I want to send text data through internet from anywhere to resberry-pi and then use text to make arduno work.

Comment: check this project out. i think you are trying to accomplish something similar

https://www.hackster.io/gokulpsamy/interfacing-arduino-with-node-red-f07882

Comment: I have all code to send text data to resberry-pi webserver, Just i want to know how to make easy way to get text data with making resberry-pi webserver easy because i want to use my for every one but if everyone need to go through this step this is a big problem.